# The buttons do not come out side by side

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-8

I'm having a problem. I set up my css by setting the buttons side by side, only it's not working.

```css
#btn1, #btn2, #btn3{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-success" id="btn1" href="{{route('wineshop.edit', compact('wineshop'))}}">EDIT</a>
<form action="{{route('wineshop.destroy', compact('wineshop'))}}" method="post">
      @method('delete')
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
</form>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3" href="{{route('wineshop.index')}}">BACK</a>
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: you have one button inside a form (having mixed content? or just the delete button?) and two buttons outisde the form. It would be much better if they were all at the same level because it's unpredictable what you are going to fill the form with and it may affects the style. After then you could use a flex container as suggested among the answers or just go with `display:inline-block` for elements required to be next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set with Outer div Flex Style

```css
#btn1, #btn2, #btn3
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  }
.btn_outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_outer">
<a class="btn btn-success" id="btn1" href="{{route('wineshop.edit', compact('wineshop'))}}">EDIT</a>
<form action="{{route('wineshop.destroy', compact('wineshop'))}}" method="post">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
</form>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3" href="{{route('wineshop.index')}}">BACK</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work yet

Comment: Could you please share image or screenshot how you want to place buttons

Comment: like you did, only it's not working for me in the code

Comment: Did you copy all html code i have given ?

Comment: yes, that's the problem

Comment: it was my problem, i forgot to run npm run dev command. A thousand thanks